# how to use teleop

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi every one. i just finished the beginners tutorial and i'm doing rosserial_arduino tutorial. i saw some video of controlling the robot using teleop package in a network by another laptop which should also be in a network. i searched, but couldnot find a clue where to start off with. please guide me where to start off.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71962/how-to-use-teleop/) by [appsdownload](https://answers.ros.org/users/5596/appsdownload/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

teleop just send geometry_msgs::Twist into /cmd_vel
your robot got this message and write signals to motors

---

Originally posted by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) with karma: 471 on 2013-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1